# How to check in a component which classes were applied to it?

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-component

I have a Vue component and would like to check, **from within this component**, which classes have been applied to it.

Is this possible?

As a workaround, I currently pass the class as a `prop`:

```
<my-component someprop="hello" classprop="red" class="red"></my-component>
```

This is a (poor) solution for static classes, it will break is the class is bound.

Answer (score 0):

You can check $vnode.data.staticClass.
From the console, logging `this` from `mounted()`

```
VueComponent {_uid: 13, …}
  ...
  $vnode
    ...
    data:
      ...
      staticClass: "myClass"
```